# CSR List thead row under items

Tags: sharepoint-online, jslink, client-side-rendering

Trying to learn CSR.  My first try looks like this:

```
(function (){
    //init
    var inCtx = {};
    inCtx.Templates = {};

    inCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverride;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(inCtx);

    function ItemOverride(itemCtx){
        var result = "";
        result += "<h3>";
        result += itemCtx.CurrentItem.Title;
        result += "</h3>";
        return result;
    }

})();
```

Result is looking good, but the thead row is now under my items. What should i do? I would like to keep it over the items...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice for is to use [Cisar for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo) what was developed by [Andrey Markeev](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/1430/andrey-markeev). It's really helpfull and quick tool. There are his [first](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views), [second](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms) and [third](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/888923/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms-p) articles about CSR.

What about your question, i think you need to override Fields templates for your list. Thanks to it, you can edit list view style by fields in items.

Example with Cisar:

```
// The file has been created, saved into "/Style Library/"
// and attached to the XLV via JSLink property.

SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

  function getBaseHtml(ctx) {
    return SPClientTemplates["_defaultTemplates"].Fields.default.all.all[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.FieldType][ctx.BaseViewID](ctx);
  }

  function init() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

      // OnPreRender: function(ctx) { },

      Templates: {

      //     View: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Header: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Body: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Group: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Item: function(ctx) { return ""; },
            Fields: {
              "ErrorText": {
                   View: function(ctx) { return ctx.CurrentItem["ErrorText"] + "this is CSR example"; },
                   EditForm: function(ctx) { return ""; },
                   DisplayForm: function(ctx) { return ""; },
                   NewForm: function(ctx) { return ""; }
               }
           },
      //     Footer: function(ctx) { return ""; }

      },

      // OnPostRender: function(ctx) { },

      ListTemplateType: 10001

    });
  }

  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/CsrFields.js"), init);
  init();

});
```

Comment: Cisar for chrome isn't working for me. I informed the developer, tool looks great on screenshoots. Thank for the links, They did help me.